# How to make some text content in a div editable on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a editbox editable when we click on div as we accomplish this by clicking on "Div editable".It work great for single id Can you please tell how to make it for multiple id's.Thanks in advance.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          Editable Div (double click text to the right, to enter edit mode)  :   
       </td>
       <td>
         <div id="makeEditable">Div editable</div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>

(function($) {
$.fn.editable = function() {
    var textBlock = $(this);
    // Create a new input to allow editing text on double click
    var textBox = $('<input/>');
    textBox.hide().insertAfter(textBlock).val(textBlock.html());

    // Hiding the div and showing a input to allow editing the value.
    textBlock.dblclick(function() {
        toggleVisiblity(true);
    });
    // Hiding the input and showing the original div
    textBox.blur(function() {
        toggleVisiblity(false);
    });

    toggleVisiblity = function(editMode) {
        if (editMode == true) {
            textBlock.hide();
            textBox.show().focus();
            // workaround, to move the cursor at the end in input box.
            textBox[0].value = textBox[0].value;
        }
        else {
            textBlock.show();
            textBox.hide();
            textBlock.html(textBox.val());
        }
    };
};

})(jQuery);
$(function() {
    var $edit = $('#makeEditable').editable();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rework your logic a little. You should create separate input for every div element and in the events you should operate over current dblclicked or blured element through `this`.  Here is [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4gM7/) with little modifications.

Hope it helps you. But I recommend to use `contenteditable` attribute as @apaul34208 suggested unless you have other custom js logic.

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify things a bit by using `contenteditable="true"`

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/fukuq/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Basic functionality

```
<div id="makeEditable" contenteditable="true">Div editable</div>
```

Optionally add some css to make it a little more user friendly

```
#makeEditable:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

[MDN Documentation for Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Comment: can it work for multiple class in place of id if we apply this on number of div's ?

Comment: @vaibhavagarwal It is just an attribute, like `width=""` or `style=""`, you can add it to as many divs as you like.

Comment: @vaibhavagarwal Is [this](http://jsbin.com/fukuq/2/edit?html,css,output) what you're looking for?

Comment: Please see this fiddle [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/veraxaqa/1/edit)
it place <textarea> when I click on reply and submit .

Comment: @vaibhavagarwal It looks like you are trying to set up a form of some kind... You may be better off just using `<input type="text"></input>` or just `<textarea></textarea>`rather than using editable divs. Is there some reason you are approaching this differently?

Comment: yes its a comment div which user can edit so I need a textarea.

Comment: @vaibhavagarwal Why not use a plain `<form><textarea></textarea></form>`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic jQuery selectors like this:
$('#makeEditable,#anotherid,#anidagain')

But if you want to do it on multiple divs/elements its better to give all the elements a class, and apply the function to all the elements with that class. Your selector will then be:
$('.editable')

Comment: Using class I tried that but on edit it show same data on edit div .Taking first div html on all selector edit.